# Unique items in python list

Tags: python

I am trying to make a unique collection of dates in a Python list.

Only add a date to the collection if it not already present in the collection.

```
timestamps = []

timestamps = [
    '2011-02-22', '2011-02-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-12-14', '2010-12-13', 
    '2010-12-12', '2010-12-11', '2010-12-07', '2010-12-02', '2010-11-30', 
    '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16']

date = "2010-11-22"
if date not in timestamps:
    timestamps.append(date)
```

How would I sort the list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use sets for this.

```
date = "2010-11-22"
timestamps = set(['2011-02-22', '2011-02-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-12-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-12-12', '2010-12-11', '2010-12-07', '2010-12-02', '2010-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16'])
#then you can just update it like so
timestamps.update(['2010-11-16']) #if its in there it does nothing
timestamps.update(['2010-12-30']) # it does add it
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will effectively do nothing. You are referencing the same variable twice (`timestamps`).

So you would have to make two seperate lists:

```
unique_timestamps= []

timestamps = ['2011-02-22', '2011-02-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-12-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-12-12', '2010-12-11', '2010-12-07', '2010-12-02', '2010-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16']

date="2010-11-22"
if(date not in timestamps):
   unique_timestamps.append(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition seems to be correct.  If you do not care about the order of the dates though, it might be easier to use a set instead of a list.  You would not need any `if` in this case:

```
timestamps = set(['2011-02-22', '2011-02-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-12-14', 
                  '2010-12-13', '2010-12-12', '2010-12-11', '2010-12-07',
                  '2010-12-02', '2010-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23',
                  '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16'])
timesteps.add("2010-11-22")
```